# av_read_frame reads frames from cache

Tags: c, libav, v4l2

I want to detect an object with my camera. For performance reason, i like to keep the connection to my camera alive and read new images on demand.

The function to read images calls `av_read_frame` till the frame is complete and then does some calculation.

My problem now is, that the frames "chain-up". If i stop frequently asking for new frames, i get old-images and not the current, because they're not yet readed (even i don't need them). If possible, i don't want to read the images with an additional thread because i don't want to waste resources on my RaspberryPi. Any ideas how to disable this "cache" or other ideas?

Comment: why don't you just access v4l2 directly?

Comment: We had different development platforms (OSX and different versions of Linux) in the beginning. That's why a big part of our code is coupled quite tight to this library...